# Reading from Json file to create graph javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, csv

I need your help.
I want to change this graph: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885211 to read from a json file instead of tsv. That is the format of my Json file.

```
{
  "name":"chrome" ,

  "values": [   
      { "time" : 1232323 , "value:" :  12}, 
      { "time" : 12323323 , "value:" : 19   
   ]},

{   
  "counter":"Mozilla" ,

  "values": [   
    { "time" : 1232sd3 , "value:" : 18}, 
    { "time" : 11232323 , "value:" : 20}   
  ]},

{    
  "name":"IE" ,

  "values": [   
    {"time" : 12387823 ,"value:" :  100},
    {"time" : 12323 ,"value:" : 123123}
  ]}

]
```

I have tried a lot but it does not work with Json file.

Really appreciate your help :(

Comment: Is there a missing `[` at the beginning of the file?

Comment: Call `JSON.parse()` and it will turn the JSON into a Javascript object, then you can do whatever you like with it.

Comment: maybe this ? https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_json

Comment: Your JSON is also incorrect. it's missing a `[` at the beginning and the time value for Mozilla `1232sd3` is incorrect. It'll raise a parse error. Otherwise, try using JSON.parse(). Look into javascript libraries and frameworks like `YUI` and `jQuery` if you need more tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. So I decided to spend some time and help you solve the problem. The conversion to JSON was poorly done (for the code that is written on the page).

A quick way to get json from the data would be to use vim to retab the data file before running it through a script like this one https://github.com/turian/common-scripts/blob/master/tsv-to-json.py

I created had to manually reformat the data (since I was just trying to set up an example) but you might want to change the code so that it writes into an array first before producing json (you may also need to change the `common.json` to `json`).

The complete example is hosted here http://jsfiddle.net/dvqFj/1/

Good luck

Comment: I have 3 data points in the json and decoupled the function. Check http://jsfiddle.net/dvqFj/3/ for comments